# Can I use machine learning to predict a functions behavior?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to use this as training data

```
(1, sin(x)), (2, sin(2x)), (3, sin(3x))
```

and answer the question what is `(20, ?)`.

I have tried using existing inbuilt machine learning functions to no avail. I tried this:

```
trainingset = {1 -> Sin[x], 2 -> Sin[2 x], 3 -> Sin[3 x], 4 -> Sin[4 x]};
p = Predict[trainingset]
```

Got an error message saying it cannot accept functions as inputs. So my question is what is the workaround for doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can use the algorithm called “Linear Regression”.  But, is this question about Mathematica?

Comment: Is it machine learning or something more traditional?

Comment: I tried this. trainingset = {1 -> Sin[x], 2 -> Sin[2 x], 3 -> Sin[3 x], 
   4 -> Sin[4 x]};

Comment: p = Predict[trainingset] . Got an error message saying it cannot accept functions as inputs. So my question is what is the workaround for doing this?

Answer (score 7):

You are running into problems because you are confusing numeric and symbolic computations.

[Predict](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html) generates regressions, i.e., it attempts to determine a numerical value.  But `Sin[2 x]` does not have a numerical value unless `x` is defined.  For example, if you change this to:

```
x = 2.;
train = # -> Sin[#*x] & /@ Range[10]
```

Then you can generate a model by:

```
model = Predict[train]
```

And generate your desired numerical prediction for the input value n = 20

`model[20] (* 0.0646506 *)`

However, you will find that this approximation is quite bad because (in Mathematica 11.3) the resulting PredictorFunction is a decision tree, which has difficulty extrapolating)

`Sin[20*x]` (*0.745113 *) `

You might be able to get better results by changing the `Method` option used for [Predict](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html).  However, a better solution to your problem is to use [FindFormula](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html), which returns a numerical expression

```
FindFormula[train, n]
(* Sin[2. n] *)
```